# Continuity of complex function extended on the compact unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:D \to \hat{\mathbb{C}}$ be a continuous function. If for all $\zeta$ in $T:=\{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$ the limit $$\lim_{w\to\zeta}f(w)$$ exists, then $f$ becomes continuous in $D \cup T$, with $D$ being the (open) unit disc. How can one see that this is true? Also, the notation $$\lim_{w\to\zeta}f(w)$$ is equivalent to saying that for every sequence $(z_n)$ with $(z_n) \to \zeta$ the limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty}f(z_n)$$ exists. However it is not directly clear, which set my sequence is from (is it from $D$ or $D \cup T?)$. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Let $(z_n)_n$ be a sequence in $D$ with $(z_n) \to z$, $z\in D$. Then $f(z_n) \to f(z)$ follows by continuity on $D$. Let $(z_n)$ be a sequence in $D$ with $(z_n) \to z$, $z \in T$. Then $lim_{n\to \infty}f(z_n)=lim_{\zeta \to z}f(\zeta)=f(z)$ per definition of the extension of f. Now since $T$ is a closed set and $D$ is open, there is no sequence in $T$ that converges to a point in $D$. What is therefore left to check is that for every sequence $(z_n)$ in $T$ with $(z_n)\to z, z\in T$, $f(z_n)\to f(z)$ also holds. Since $z \in T$, for every sequence $(a_n)$ in $D$ with $(a_n) \to z$, $f(a_n)\to f(z)$ follows as explained above.This is equivalent to saying that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ so that for every $w \in B(z,\delta)\cap D$, $|f(z)-f(w)|<\epsilon$ follows. It is left to show that this also holds for all $v \in B(z,\delta)\cap \bar{D}$, since then for every sequence $(a_n)$ in $\bar{D}$ with $(a_n)\to z$ it follows that $f(a_n) \to f(z)$. We only need to take a look at $v \in B(z,\delta)\cap \bar{D}$ now since it is already shown that the statement is true for all other points. Since $v \in \bar{D}$, there exists a sequence $(w_n)$ in $D$ with $(w_n)\to v$, which again implies $f(w_n)\to f(v)$. Suppose now $|f(z)-f(v)|> \epsilon$ for one $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: @copper.hat thank you for your comment. Could you explain your proof of the continuity in a bit more detail? I know that f is continuous in $D$ and for sequences in $D$ with limit in $T$. I then need to check, that for sequences in $T$ with limit in $T$ it is continuous too, since a sequence in $T$ with limit in $D$ can't exist.

Comment: Actually, I think I am wrong, I was assuming something about uniformity. Given me a few minutes.

Comment: What do you mean by $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$?

Comment: @copper.hat It is $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the extended $f$ satisfies $f(z) = \lim_{w \to z,w \in D} f(w)$. This is true by continuity for $z \in D$ and by definition (and the fact that by assumption the limit exists for any sequence $w_n \in D \to z$).

Suppose $z_k \to z$ with $z_k \in D$ then clearly $f(z_k) \to f(z)$ by continuity if $z \in D$ and by definition if $z \in T$.

So the only other sequences are those for which $z_k \to z$ and $z_k \in T$ infinitely
often (in which case we must have $z \in T$). We need to show that $f(z_k) \to f(z)$.

If $f(z)$ is finite, then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that
if $w \in B(z,\delta) \cap D$ we have $|f(w)-f(z)| < \epsilon$. It follows that
for any $w \in B(z,\delta) \cap \overline{D}$ that $|f(w)-f(z)| \le \epsilon$ and so
$f(z_k) \to f(z)$.

**Elaboration**: Suppose the if $w \in B(z,\delta) \cap D$ we have $|f(w)-f(z)| < \epsilon$ condition holds, and $v \in B(z,\delta) \cap \overline{D}$. Then there is some sequence $w_n \in B(z,\delta) \cap D$ such that $w_n \to v$, and since
$|f(z)-f(w_n)| < \epsilon$ for all $n$ and $w_n \to v$ we have $|f(z)-f(v)| \le \epsilon$.

If $f(z) $ is infinite, then for any $N>0$ there is some $\delta>0$  such that
if $w \in B(z,\delta) \cap D$ we have $|f(w)| > N$. It follows that
for any $w \in B(z,\delta) \cap \overline{D}$ that $|f(w)| \ge N$ and so
$f(z_k) \to f(z)$

**Addendum**: Let me clarify the claim that if $f(z)$ is finite, then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that
if $w \in B(z,\delta) \cap D$ we have $|f(w)-f(z)| < \epsilon$.
Recall that $f(z) = \lim_{w \to z,w \in D} f(w)$ for all $z \in D \cup T$.
Suppose it is not true, then there is some $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence $w_n \in B(z,\delta) \cap D$ such that $|f(w_n)-f(z)| \ge \epsilon$ for all $n$, which
contradicts the limit definition of $f$.

As similar analysis shows the case when $f(z)$ is infinite.

---

Here is a rewrite of the answer that avoids distinctions of sequences:

Let $f^*(z) = \lim_{w \to z,w \in D} f(w)$. We see that $f^*(z) = f(z) $ for $z \in D$ by continuity and this is how $f^*$ is defined for $z \in T$. By assumption $f^*(z)$ exists for $z \in T$ (this is a fairly strong assumption).

We want to show that $f^*$ is continuous on $D \cup T$. Note that $T = \partial D$,
hence any $z \in T$ can be approached by a sequence $z_n \in D$.

Suppose we pick $z \in D \cup T$. I will prove continuity for the case where $f^*(z)$ is finite, the infinite case is similar.

By the limit definition of $f^*$, we have the following: For all $z \in D \cup T$ and $\epsilon>0$
there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|f^*(z)-f^*(w)| < \epsilon$ for $w \in B(z,\delta) \cap D$. (See the addendum above for a proof.)
Since this is true for all $w \in B(z,\delta) \cap D$, if $w' \in B(z,\delta) \cap \overline{D}$, we can find a sequence $w_n \to w'$ with $w_n \in B(z,\delta) \cap D$ and hence we have $|f^*(z)-f^*(w)| \le \epsilon$ for $w \in B(z,\delta) \cap \overline{D}$. (This follows from continuity of $|\cdot|$ and the fact that $[0,\epsilon]$ is closed.)

In particular, this shows that $f^*$ is continuous at $z$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105312/discussion-on-answer-by-copper-hat-continuity-of-complex-function-extended-on-th).